# What is this plastic toy?

Tags: object-identification, toys

I found this sci-fi model toy in my house. What is it supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Takara-Pokemon-Monster-Collection-Figure/dp/B00564YWVI

Comment: @DavidW looks like a cheap knockoff of it... Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Wow, that is a terrible paint job on that.  You can even see the lines where those bow-things are supposed to go but they missed by quite a bit, didn't even bother with the hands or the hair bow, etc.  Surprised anyone would let that out of the factory.  (Someone should send this to Phelous...)

Comment: The bows are painted as black on this figurine.

Comment: I remember having a bag full of plaster made Pokémon. A bunch of them had some wrong colours. I don't know if they were actually sold like that, or if they were sold clear and someone painted them wrong. Somehow, that toy reminds me of these.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This looks like a fairly cheap model of the [Gothitelle](https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/gothitelle) Pokémon.

[image: Gothitelle]

I found this similar but better quality Takara Tomy model [for sale](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Takara-Pokemon-Monster-Collection-Figure/dp/B00564YWVI):

[image: Takara Tomy model of Gothitelle]